# How do I match a word that occurs at any point before another word, and NOT after that word?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to look at job descriptions that mention veterans but only when it's not in the equal opportunity employer disclaimer.

Say you were given the following text:

```
A) We love veterans!

B) We are an equal opportunity employer and value diversity at our company. We do not discriminate on the basis of race, religion, color, national origin, gender, sexual orientation, age, marital status, veteran status, or disability status.

C) We love veterans! We are an equal opportunity employer and value diversity at our company. We do not discriminate on the basis of race, religion, color, national origin, gender, sexual orientation, age, marital status, veteran status, or disability status.
```

I would like to match A but not B, but also match with C since it is mentioned before and after equal, but I only really care if it matches before or not.

This is what I've tried: `veteran*.+(?=\s+equal)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a look ahead on a dot, and anchor the match from start:

```
^(?i)((?!\bequal\b).)*veteran
```

Word boundaries added to `equal` so it still allows `equalize` etc.

`(?i)` turns case insensitivity on.

Comment: Wow thanks, this is almost perfect! How can I make the "veteran" part case insensitive? Like this? `(?i)^((?!\bequal\b).)*veteran`

Comment: @AdhiR. add `(?i)` to turn on case insensitivity. See edited answer. To make only “veteran” case insensitive, put `(?i)` just before it.